# Preventing Deploy When Previous Stage Failed on GItlab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml, config

I have the following stages defined in my project's `gitlab-config.yaml`:

```
stages:
  - Prepare
  - Report
  - Static Analysis
  - Unit Test
  - Integration Test Prep
  - Integration Tests
  - Deploy
```

The stage before `Deploy` is `Integration Tests`, and all jobs within this stage are not allowed to fail (which is the default according to [the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure)).

I have a number of deploy jobs that deploy to different environments. My production deploy job uses the following logic:

```
  rules:
    - if: $DEPLOY_ENV == "production" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "production"
      when: always
```

My problem with the current setup is that even though the Integration Tests jobs are not allowed to fail, even if they do, the production deploy stage is still reached.

It appears that the use of `always` overrides the fact that the previous stage's jobs are not allowed to fail.

**How can I prevent the production deploy job from running if any of the previous Integration Tests jobs fail?**

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use the `always` option in the when config? Otherwise I would recommend using `on_success` instead.

Comment: @pat If you want to write that up as an answer I'll happily delete mine and give you the win.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use `on_success` instead of `always` ([docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when)):

```
  rules:
    - if: $DEPLOY_ENV == "production" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "production"
      when: on_success
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **needs** keyword (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs) to specify more complex dependencies between jobs

```yaml
jobA:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building"

jobB:
  stage: build
  needs: ["jobA"]
  script: echo "Another Build"
```